# ESP8266 and Android socket won't communicate

Tags: java, android, sockets, esp8266

I am having issues getting my Android device and an ESP8266 communicate using sockets. Here is the code for the ESP8266:

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>
#include <WebSocketsServer.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <Hash.h>

ESP8266WebServer server = ESP8266WebServer(80);
WebSocketsServer webSocket = WebSocketsServer(81);

void webSocketEvent(uint8_t num, WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length) {
  switch (type) {
    case WStype_DISCONNECTED:
      Serial.printf("[%u] Disconnected!\n", num);
      break;
    case WStype_CONNECTED: {
        IPAddress ip = webSocket.remoteIP(num);
        Serial.printf("[%u] Connected from %d.%d.%d.%d url: %s\n", num, ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3], payload);

        // send message to client
        webSocket.sendTXT(num, "Connected");
      }
      break;
    case WStype_TEXT:
      IPAddress ip = webSocket.remoteIP(num);
      Serial.printf("$%s?\n", payload);
      webSocket.sendTXT(num, payload, sizeof(payload), false);
      break;
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  for (uint8_t t = 4; t > 0; t--) {
    Serial.printf("[SETUP] BOOT WAIT %d...\n", t);
    Serial.flush();
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.println("Starting AP");
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
  WiFi.softAP("Alpine_SIM_CNTRL", "12345678");
  Serial.println("AP Started");

  Serial.println("Starting Socket");
  // start webSocket server
  webSocket.begin();
  webSocket.onEvent(webSocketEvent);
  Serial.println("Socket Started");

  if (MDNS.begin("simcontrol")) {
    Serial.println("MDNS responder started");
  }
  Serial.println("Starting Server");
  //handle index
  server.on(
  "/", []() {
    server.send(200, "text/plain", "You are connected");
  });

  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server Started");

  //Add service to MDNS
  MDNS.addService("http", "tcp", 80);
  MDNS.addService("ws", "tcp", 81);
}

void loop() {
  webSocket.loop();
  server.handleClient();
}
```

And below is the Java code for the socket for Android:

```java
public class WriteToServer extends AsyncTask<MyTaskParams, Void, String> {
  Context context;
  Socket socket;

  public WriteToServer(MyTaskParams Params) {
  }

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(MyTaskParams... params) {
    socket = null;
    DataInputStream in = null;
    DataOutputStream out = null;
    context = params[0].context;
    String command = params[0].cmd;
    String response = null;
    try {
      socket = new Socket("192.168.4.1", 81);
      out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
      in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
      out.writeUTF(command);
      Log.i("Command", "Command sent: " + command);
      while (in.available() > 0) {
        response = in.readUTF();
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      Log.e("Error", "There was an error writing to the socket. Thrown IO exception");
    } finally {
      if (socket != null) {
        try {
          Log.i("INFO", "closing the socket");
          socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      if (in != null) {
        try {
          in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      if (out != null) {
        try {
          out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
    return response;
  }
}
```

Can anyone please point out why I am not getting any communication? Using the debugger in Android Studio I can see that the socket is connected to the correct address and port, but when I send something to the ESP it does not print out what I sent or respond back. If I connect to the ESP with my PC and type in 192.168.4.1:81/*** I get a response that states "This is a websocket server only". So I think the socket server should be up and running based on this. Any help would be appreciated.

**[EDIT]**
Thanks to response from Codo I know I was using two different socket technologies on the server and client. I am now using Java WebSockets. I can now see on the ESP that the Android device is trying to connect but the ESP closes the connection right away. Below is from Debug of ESP device:

```
[WS-Server][0] new client from 192.168.4.2
[WS-Server][0][handleHeader] RX: GET / HTTP/1.1
[WS-Server][0][handleHeader] RX: Connection: Upgrade
[WS-Server][0][handleHeader] RX: Host: 192.168.4.1:81
[WS-Server][0][handleHeader] RX: Sec-WebSocket-Key: LmtO2xH7n9k+KKJNN/4+GA==
[WS-Server][0][handleHeader] RX: Sec-WebSocket-Version: 8
[WS-Server][0][handleHeader] RX: Upgrade: websocket
[WS-Server][0][handleHeader] Header read fin.
[WS-Server][0][handleHeader]  - cURL: /
[WS-Server][0][handleHeader]  - cIsUpgrade: 1
[WS-Server][0][handleHeader]  - cIsWebsocket: 1
[WS-Server][0][handleHeader]  - cKey: LmtO2xH7n9k+KKJNN/4+GA==
[WS-Server][0][handleHeader]  - cProtocol:
[WS-Server][0][handleHeader]  - cExtensions: <null>
[WS-Server][0][handleHeader]  - cVersion: 8
[WS-Server][0][handleHeader]  - base64Authorization:
[WS-Server][0][handleHeader]  - cHttpHeadersValid: 1
[WS-Server][0][handleHeader]  - cMandatoryHeadersCount: 0
[WS-Server][0][handleHeader] no Websocket connection close.
[WS-Server][0] client disconnected.
```

Can anyone help me figure out why the ESP is closing the connection?

**[Update and Fix]**
I have fixed the issue. When creating the socket on the Android device using org.java.websockets I was using:

```
mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri)
```

I found that if you don't assign the draft version when creating the socket that it defaults to websockets Version 8 which won't work with the ESP8266(at least not with the arduinowebsockets library. I had to create the socket using the following:

```
mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri, new Draft_17())
```

After this the websocket is created as version 13 which now works.

The issue is now fixed!

Comment: You are mixing two different concepts: In Java, you use the rather low-level [Unix sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) and on the ESP you use [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), which are closely related to HTTP. Get a proper WebSocket client library for Java.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions? I have literally started programming with Java/Android about three weeks ago so I am a little lost on where to find a proper library.Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't have experience with a WebSocket client in Java. So far I've implemented the client side in Javascript as the setup was different than your's. It seems that Java EE implements everything needed for WebSockets (client and server side). So take a look at this [example](http://www.programmingforliving.com/2013/08/jsr-356-java-api-for-websocket-client-api.html). It might be helpful. I don't really understand the dependencies as Java EE separates the general interface from the implementation, which makes things more complex in this case.

Comment: Codo thank you very much for your response. I feel you have me headed in the right direction now. But I am now having issues with the correct websocket library. Please see edit on main post with the update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing two different concepts: In Java, you use the rather low-level Unix sockets and on the ESP you use WebSocket, which are closely related to HTTP. Get a proper WebSocket client library for Java. – Codo Jan 4 at 17:33